# MATLAB GUI, how to extract words from Static Text in GUI?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I'm using MATLAB GUI. In my project I've loaded a file and displayed the content in the Static Text but I want it to be a more readable version to display in the interface for users.

This is the content of the file:

```
!MLF!#

"*/test001.rec"

0 200000 sent-start -162.580292

200000 4500000 five -2768.522217

4500000 7900000 five -2114.920898

7900000 12300000 one -2661.298828

12300000 15800000 two -2209.799805

15800000 29800000 sent-end -6030.099609
.
```

Is there a way to extract words from the Static Text in the GUI, and then convert the "five five one two" to "5512"?

This is my current coding:

```
data1 = importdata('C:\Users\User\Desktop\bin.win32\recout.mlf','') 
set(handles.txtMsg, 'Max', 2); 
set(handles.txtMsg,'String',data1) 

%capturedString = get(handles.txtMsg,'String');
%capturedString = strjoin(captureString')

capturedString = 'nine one';
%StaticTextInString = regexprep(captureString,'[^\w'']','')

WordsToDigit=find(not(cellfun('isempty',strfind({'zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'},capturedString)))) - 1;

set(handles.txtMsg,'String',WordsToDigit);'
```

Let's assume `capturedString = 'nine one'` first,

If I let the `capturedString = 'nine'`, then `WordsToDigit = '9'`. However, if there is more than one word such as the one above: "nine one", then the outcome would be "Empty matrix: 1-by-0".

Is that possible to detect multiple sub-string in a string?

For example, `capturedString = "dasd 312 nine wqej seven 98w one"`, `WordsToDigit = '971'`.

Comment: Have you tried to use lookup table to convert numbers in form of words into numbers?

Comment: Could you share your code? Do you access it from a callback function so that you have access to the handles structure and can read the Static Text in the following way: StaticTextInString = get(handles.yourstatictext,'String');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get Static Text from the GUI in to the string. For example, if you have access to the handles structure:

```
StaticTextInString = get(handles.yourstatictext,'String');
```

Afterwards, if you have only digits in the form of words, you can get the digit number using the following function:

```
find(not(cellfun('isempty',strfind({'zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'},StaticTextInString ))))-1
```

For example for StaticTextInString = 'five' the previous command return 5.

The extension for the multiple words:

```
capturedString = 'dasd 312 nine wqej seven 98w one'
words = strread(capturedString,'%s','delimiter',' ');
digits = {'zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'};
WordsToDigit = 0;
j = 1;
for i = 1:size(words)
    if sum(ismember(digits, words(i)))==1
        newdigit = find(not(cellfun('isempty',strfind({'zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'}, char(words(i)) ))))-1;
        WordsToDigit = WordsToDigit*10 + newdigit;
        j=j+1;
    end
end
```

Results with WordsToDigit  = 971

Comment: You can use strread('dasd 312 nine wqej seven 98w one','%s','delimiter',' ') to split string if you have Matlab version lower than 2013a or simply strsplit('dasd 312 nine wqej seven 98w one') if you have newer version.